# bash command to find a specific bit of info in a line of a text file?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm running a command that outputs this to /tmp/foo.txt:

```
Title: 01, Length: 01:39:03.734 Chapters: 15, Cells: 17, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 04
Title: 02, Length: 00:00:01.000 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 00, Subpictures: 00
Title: 03, Length: 00:00:01.500 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 04, Length: 00:00:01.500 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 05, Length: 00:00:01.500 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 06, Length: 00:01:22.100 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 07, Length: 00:02:51.233 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 08, Length: 00:13:56.834 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 09, Length: 00:05:24.700 Chapters: 05, Cells: 06, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 10, Length: 00:24:02.100 Chapters: 02, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 11, Length: 00:00:00.500 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 04
Title: 12, Length: 00:00:00.500 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 04
```

How can I find the line that has the longest title (in this case it's Title 01 but it won't always be the first line/title) THEN get the title number, stripping away the leading zero if there is one?

Comment: Are 'titles' always numeric?  Could they be text containing commas?  Is using `awk` an option? GNU `awk`?  Is 'Title: 01` still the longest title after you strip away leading zeros?

Comment: What have you tried? Here's an idea: 1. Use awk, it's perfect for such tasks. 2. For each line use `gensub` to split the length (4th field) into 4 variables. 3. multiply the variables accordingly, to get the length in milliseconds as a single number. 4. Store length in an associative array indexed by title. 5. After reading all lines, iterate the array and find the longest. 6. Print it.

Comment: Is the title length the number/colon sequence after `Length`, or is it the text after `Title:`?  It's a nuisance that there isn't a comma after the value after `Length` —is that really like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of messy in bash, and it needs awk. You'd probably be better off using Python or something instead, but anyway, here's how you can do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset longest_milliseconds
while read -r line; do
  milliseconds=$(awk '{ print $4 }' <<<"$line" | awk -F: '{ print $1 * 3600000 + $2 * 60000 + $3 * 1000 }')
  if [[ -z ${longest_milliseconds+x} || $milliseconds -gt $longest_milliseconds ]]; then
    longest_milliseconds=$milliseconds
    longest_title=$(awk -F,?\  '{ print $2 * 1 }' <<<"$line")
  fi
done < /tmp/foo.txt
echo "$longest_title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this will scale on a large file size but I have tested this on your sample file and it seems to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob                                                                                                                                                                             

max=0
all=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
  all+=("$line")
  lines=${line#*,}
  lines=${lines#*:}
  lines=${lines#*[[:space:]]}
  lines=${lines%%[[:space:]]*}
  [[ $lines > $max ]] && max=$lines
done < /tmp/foo.txt

while read -ra line1; do
  for i in "${!line1[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${line1[$i]} == *$max* ]]; then
      longest=${line1[$i-2]%,*}
      printf '%s' "${longest##+(0)}"
    fi
  done
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${all[@]}")
```

By the way I'm using bash4+ so I don't know if that will work on bash3.